# A shortcut to move a window between workspaces in LXDE

Tags: workspace, lxde

Is there a way to move an app window between desktops via keyboard shortcut(s)?

I mean something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→ (right arrow)</kbd> to move the window to the right desktop, and/or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑ (up arrow)</kbd> to move the window to the upper desktop, etc.

BTW, I'm on LXDE.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> should do this.

I feel it is a little laggy when I use it for the first time (maybe loading something). But after the first one it works great.

source: https://daveden.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/lubuntu-keyboard-shortcuts-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> doesn't do it for me (on Lubuntu 18.04).

However it can be done with the keyboard like:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (to open window menu)
- <kbd>s</kbd> ("Send to desktop")
- <kbd>arrows</kbd> (to select desktop)
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

(I know, it's an unacceptable number of key presses.)